# Compiling Spark program: no 'lib' directory

Tags: apache-spark

I am going through the tutorial:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/apache_spark_deployment.htm

When I got to the `Step 2: Compile program` section I got stuck, because there is no `lib` folder in the `spark` directory which looks the following way:

[image]

Where is the `lib` folder? How could I compile the program? 
I looked into the `jars` folder but there is no file named `spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar`

Comment: First of all, 1.4.0 is a very old version of spark, are you sure that you want to use this version? It is always better to use sbt (scala build tool) to manage dependencies, not provide them by hand. You can look at https://github.com/addmeaning/spark-wordcount-example where I provided sample project that works

Comment: This tutorial isn't good. Please refer to the official documentation if you wish to learn Spark

Comment: @addmeaning I am learning Spark right on the cluster and sbt can be installed if I have root privileges. If it can be done without it, please, share info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I am not answering your question directly, but I want to guide you to the more convenient development process of Spark application.

When you are developing Spark application on your local computer you should use sbt (scala build tool). After you done writing code you should compile it with sbt (running `sbt assembly`). Sbt will produce 'fat jar' archive, that already has all required dependencies for a job. Then you should upload jar to spark cluster (for example using `spark-submit` script). 
There is no reason to install sbt on your cluster because it is needed only for compilation.

You should check starter [project](https://github.com/addmeaning/spark-wordcount-example) that I created for you.